# How to convert ASP.NET controls in HTML runtime

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to add an asp.net image control () in a panel at runtime.

I have the asp.net code in the label text as **`<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="test.png"/>`** (its just a example)

When I added this label in the panel control with:
**`pnlPlaceHolderPanel.Controls.Add(htmlLabel);`**

The image does not display. When I checked the HTML using **inspect element in the browser**, the element displayed in **`<asp:Image>`**, but it should be **`<img>`** tag of HTML.

So does anybody know how should I convert that asp.net design code into HTML code?

Comment: dude, asp tags should be `<asp:Image ...` note the colon, cause your question used a dot `.` (i.e. `<asp.Image>`... is that just a typo...... cause if it isn't, you just made a custom tag called `<asp.Image>` and ASP.NET not going to do anything with it and just send it to the browser as is....

Comment: Check what @OJay had said as well as are you defining the id of the image tag and using the same at the time of adding into the panel?

Comment: @OJay , yeah i have added the text as "<asp:Image>" only

Comment: @NawazKhan , i am using the id of the label in which i have text asp.net image control, and not the image id

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference ASP.Net Controls with the : sign:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="test.png" />
```

where the asp: is the namespace reference where the control is located.
As a [reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_basic_controls.htm)

Comment: yes i have used "<asp:Image>" only, i have updated the question.

Comment: nope, that asp.net text also contains <asp:Panel>, it should be rendered as <div> but its not happening, it is rendered as it is.

Comment: I think you have a major problem in your asp.net project. How did you create your project?